# How can I demonstrate knowledge of something for a job position?

Tags: job-search, job-description

I am applying for a pharma company and one of their requirements is "
Knowledge of the Canadian reimbursement system" well there isnt actually a certification for this and they are accepting new grads (like myself). I'm not sure how can I demonstrate knowledge about this? (all I can do is google it and read papers on it, there are no certificates needed to be taken for this).

Comment: Well... if you know something you know it, there is no way to fake that. Your question depends on *how* are they going to evaluate you... a test? a detailed interview?... could you rephrase your question so it is more answerable? Anyways, if you study that topic you should be able to demonstrate knowledge on it

Comment: What is your major in college?

Comment: @scaaahu Biology. So it is relevant to the field.

Answer (score 5):

In my (also Canadian) experience, when a job application asks for "knowledge of X" they generally mean *past experience working with X*.  So, the ideal candidate would have worked in position(s) where they had to deal with the Canadian reimbursement system.  You would demonstrate such knowledge by relating your past work experience with the subject and how you skillfully used it to achieve company goals.

Lacking such experience from previous jobs, all you really CAN do is google the subject and try to learn as much about it as possible before the interview.  When answering questions about it, it would probably be wise to clarify that you've researched the subject, but never actually worked with it professionally.

The good news is, at least in Canada, job requirements tend to be padded with lots of "wishlist" items.  Some of those skills are absolutely necessary, of course, but others will be more "nice-to-have" things.  (The mandatory ones tend to be at the top and use stronger language - ie: "Must know C++" vs "C++ knowledge an asset.")

If you're applying for a job in payroll, for example, knowledge of the Canadian reimbursement system is probably mandatory and you should really know what you're talking about when you go in.  If you're applying for a general administration or secretarial role, it might be more of a bonus - makes you a better candidate if you've worked with it before, but you can still do the job without it.

Just be honest about your level of experience, and try to learn as much as you can before the interview.

Comment: +1 - I'd also add that what they're doing is evaluating how much of a "training load" onboarding an applicant will be.  If you can demonstrate that you are good at "self-learning," that will make a huge difference!

Comment: @Steve-O  thank you for answering my question. The requirement is actually an asset.They did not mention anything about the number of years in the job field. Also, this is what they had in the description "Essential Requirements:Are you a university graduate whose area of study is marketing, business, or a science related field?Do you aspire to an experience which offers daily opportunities to learn and grow?" I really want to get to the interview to demonstrate to them how I am a quicklearner and passionate!What do you recommend that I add in my CV that conveys my ability of self-learning?